# AngularJS manual initialization

Tags: javascript, angularjs

from the example provided on the page https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/bootstrap, I can see manual initialization like this

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<body>
  Hello {{'World'}}!
  <script src="http://code.angularjs.org/angular.js"></script>

  <script>
    angular.module('myApp', [])
      .controller('MyController', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
        $scope.greetMe = 'World';
      }]);

    angular.element(document).ready(function() {
      angular.bootstrap(document, ['myApp']);
    });
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

actually it does not work well, but anyway I want to have it working like this, I don't want to explicitly specify my controller in ng-controller directive just to have it there. I would like to bind this controller to whole page without extra manipulations with HTML. Because I want to use it only for ajax call. Is it possible?

Comment: If all you want to use angular for is to make an ajax call, then why are you using angular? Angular does a lot of things very well, but the cost in library size does not seem warranted for just an ajax call, can you please explain?

Comment: Yes, I know that. But I also know that in the future I may use not only ajax calls in my project. So this is just the first step. I simply want to know whether it's possible to attach a controller to my view without pointing out it in my HTML. Because if I already pointed it out in my JS so why I need to tell HTML about that additionally. You see my point.

Answer (score 0):

The browser can not find the resource http://code.angularjs.org/angular.js 
Look at the network panel on your browser (developer tools) is returning a 404 error.
Try with https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.0-beta.6/angular.min.js

Comment: You're making some assumptions that the OP is not experiencing.

Comment: the example works fine, 
the problem is that the angularjs resource can not be loaded
http://jsfiddle.net/#&togetherjs=L3Q7CCrQFV

Comment: But the OP didn't say that s/he was experiencing that problem.

Comment: Yes, sometimes you mistakenly think that it works well, but actually not. Look at "Hello {{'World'}}!". I guess you see that it should be "Hello {{greetMe}}!". Actually yes this sample looks strange to me. But I still wondering whether it can be working like so, without pointing ngController directive.

Comment: mmm.. ok, can you use jquery?
http://jsfiddle.net/ainara/D9QLk/
you can add ng-controller attribute on document.ready

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create an object that is used specifically for AJAX calls, then you should look into AngularJS [services](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/services). Services are objects that can be injected into controllers, other services, and directives, and they usually provide some sort of reusable functionality (in your case it would provide AJAX functionality).

The purpose of a controller is to provide logic for interacting with the view. If you are creating a controller that does not interact with the view in some way, then you are doing something wrong.

Your ajax service might look something like this:

```
<script>
    var myApp = angular.module('myApp', [])
        // notice the inclusion of 'myAjax' here. This is where we are injecting our
        // custom service that me made.
        .controller('MyController', ['$scope', 'myAjax', function ($scope, myAjax) {

            $scope.url = 'cutepuppies.com';
            $scope.params = {
                cutenessLevel: 'extraCute'
            };

            function successcb(data, status, headers, config) {
                //something on success
            }
            function failure(data, status, headers, config) {
                //something on failure
            }
            $scope.get = function () {
                // This is where we use our service to make an ajax call!
                // We also pass in 2 callbacks, one to be called on success and one on error
                myAjax.get($scope.url, $scope.params, successcb, failurecb);
            }
        }]);

    // Here we define our service. This is what we will use in our app to make ajax calls.
    myApp.service('myAjax', ['$http', function ($http) {
        return {
            get: function (url, params, successcb, failurecb) {
                $http.get({
                    method: 'GET',
                    url: url,
                    params: params
                })
                .success(successcb)
                .error(failurecb);
            }
        }
    });

</script>
```

Here's a link to the $http service for reference: [https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/%24http)

Comment: Thanks for your response and sample. But my question is about something different. The sample I've provided works well if I add ng-controller="MyController" directive into 'body' tag. That's why I'm asking whether it's possible to avoid this manipulation with HTML and use only JS controller declaration for whole view.

Comment: I don't fully understand what you are trying to do, but you might want to look into the `.run()` angular module method. Using the `.run()` method you can create **run blocks** that will be called on startup once all of your dependencies have loaded. Here is a link to the modules documentation, search for "run blocks": https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/module